# Experiencing mouse lag after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, mouse, windows-8.1

After I upgraded my PC to **Window 8.1** I'm experiencing mouse lag when playing any of my `Call of Duty` games.

I'm using an Anker 8000 USB mouse and the lag is really noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for this problem and found similar issue on this [page](http://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/1oor43/windows_81_warning_for_gamers_issues_with/)

The following steps helped me to overcame it:

1. Right click the EXE of the game in question.
2. Go to properties
3. Go to the compatibility tab
4. Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select "Windows 8."
5. Check "Disable scaling on high DPI settings."
6. Check "Run this program as an administrator."

Comment: Looks like Microsoft released an official patch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2908279